# C# my parameter does not exist in current context

Tags: c#

Hello I am new to programming, and I am getting stuck on getting it so if I press a button it adds 100 to an int called xAxis and draws a new rectangle on that xAxis.

```
 int xAxisRec = 100;

    public void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
        g.DrawRectangle(blackPen, xAxisRec, 100, 100, 100);
    }

    public void plusRec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        xAxisRec += 100;
        Form1_Paint(sender, pe);
    }
```

The problem I am having is when I run this code I get the error message "The name 'pe' does not exist in the current context" and I don't know how to fix this, the error is occurring on this line

```
Form1_Paint(sender, pe);
```

Its probably a silly mistake but I just don't know what I have done wrong, thank you for taking time to read this.

Comment: `Form1_Paint(sender, pe);` Tell us what you think `pe` is, and where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh the page, rather than calling `Form1_Paint` you want to call:

```
this.Refresh();
```